# Deriving a demand curve intermediate microeconomics

Tags: calculus, economics

The exercise says as follows: Zac consumes only pizza and Chianti in fixed proportions. 2slices of pizza per 1 glass of chianti. income is $100. Derive demand functions for pizza and Chianti.

How do I do that without knowing Zac's utility?  I know that to derive a demand curve you gotta have the utility and the budget constrain , you put the utility in the budget constrain and you have it right? But not in this case, it seems it is rather easy to solve but I dont know how to start...any clues?

Answer (score 1):

What a coincidence, I'm guessing this is for econ201? I used 0.5P = C as my optimal relation condition and then plugged the condition into the budget set to get the demand functions.